# O que é um operador unário

Tags: bash, shell-script

Código:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Digite 1:"
read$TESTE

if [ $TESTE == 654 ]
    then
    echo "Usage: ./pingscript.sh [network]"
    echo "example: ./pingscript.sh 192.168.20"
fi
```

Mensagem de erro:

```
Digite 1:
321
./z.sh: linha 5: [: ==: esperado operador unário
```

A que o interpretador se refere quando diz operadou unário?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Operadores unários é uma "instrução" composta por dois símbolos, que não precisam estar necessariamente entre dois termos (variáveis, etc).

Ao se referir ao operador unário, o interpretador refere-se a sua sequencia comparação `==` que está sendo usada de forma errada.

No caso do seu código, o erro é dado por causa do jeito que se usa o operador. O operador `==` faz a comparação de duas *Strings* em em *ShellScript*.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Digite 1:"
read TESTE # Não existe cifrão na atribuição do valor em uma variável

if [ "$TESTE" == "654" ]; then
    echo "Usage: ./pingscript.sh [network]"
    echo "example: ./pingscript.sh 192.168.20"
fi
```

No caso de comparação de valores numéricos, ou existência de arquivos, etc. Usa-se operadores do *SH* específicos para isso.

- **-eq** (Igualdade)
- **-le** (Menor ou igual)
- **-lt** (Menor que)
- **-ge** (Maior ou igual)
- **-gt** (Maior que)

---

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Digite 1:"
read TESTE

if [ $TESTE -eq 654 ]
    then
    echo "Usage: ./pingscript.sh [network]"
    echo "example: ./pingscript.sh 192.168.20"
fi
```

Comment: Você ainda pode cair num problema nesse exemplo com o `-eq` se o cara não entrar com o valor de teste; sei lá, talvez seja um pipeline em que a entrada já tenha terminado ou ele simplesmente apertou enter no teclado. Recomendo sempre expandir as variáveis com as aspas ao redor, tipo `[ "$TESTE" -eq 654 ]`